# How can I create a "show full article" button that bypasses smart paging?

Tags: uri

I am using smart paging currently but would like to create a button above my articles that would show the entire article on a single page (canonical link) that would also have no pagination (bypass smart paging entirely for that link). I'm not finding any solutions on how to do this. Is it even possible? These links are for search engine indexing so that the non paginated version would serve as a landing page for search results traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used smart paging, but from looking at the docs and the code I would say this is currently not possible. My suggestion in this case would be to create a feature request in the modules issue queue.

Answer (score 0):

My work around was to modify the smart_paging-pager.js by adding an option tag. So right 
before ....

`js_box += '</select></li>';`

add...

`//Create option to view full article
        js_box += '<option> ' + selected + ' value="' + base_url + '/' + current_url + '?nopaging=1' + '"' + Drupal.t('Page: Full Article ')  + '</option>';`

Problem though if you update the module be sure to add the option back into the js file